# Sending friend request from dynamic links(React native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I am developing a new react native app and I have difficulty understanding if it's possible to send a dynamic link that redirects the one opening the link 1. To app store if they haven't installed the app yet but if already installed, redirect them to a friend request page, where they are presented with accept or decline buttons.(It's basically sending a friend request through a link where the link is sent either by sms text or other social medias). I would appreciate if anyone has a way to do it. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this feature is not available if you're using Expo, however if you're using Bare-bone RN then you'll be able to use the native modules provided from Firebase to initialize the dynamic links, [this](https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage) page shows detailed documentation on how to implement the feature you need for your app.